# password_verify Not Returning Anything

Tags: php, passwords, password-encryption, password-hash

When I run the code below password_verify is not returning anything. I tried echoing to see what was coming back and nothing is printing.

I echoed the stored pw as well to make sure that wasn't the problem and it isn't. I echoed the user input and that also seems to be working fine.

One of the passwords I used was grayson, hashed it is $2y$10$iK5pADTskgcfo6KRnBXs3e/0LkclrsZb3DSo1bmLubLqd.aaIdnK2

```
<?php
    $loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
    $loginPassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cjramire_wrdp1", 'password', "username");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $loginEmail)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['password'];
    echo $loginPassword;
    $verify = password_verify($loginPassword, $row['password']);
    echo $verify;
    if($verify){
        echo "Its a match";
    }else{
        echo "nope";
    }
```

Let me know if any other info helps and thanks!

Below I am adding the code I used to push the info into the database as you can see the pws are hashed before they are pushed to the database.

```
$signUpEmail =  $_POST['signUpEmail'];
$signUpPassword = $POST['signUpPassword'];
$hash = password_hash($signUpPassword,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cjramire_wrdp1", 'password', "username");
$query = "INSERT INTO `Users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('$signUpEmail', '$hash')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: password_verify is a custom function or any MVC method? Please specify the framework or cms.thanks

Comment: So, "nope" is also not getting printed?

Comment: Show the password_verify function code . It must return TRUE or FALSE according to your code , otherwise it may also return '1' or '0' and you have to check with 1 or 0 in this file and show result .

Comment: Are your passwords being stored on you db as a hash created by the `password_hash()` function?

Comment: Hi @Carlos Ramirez,
You missed "password_verify" function. this is custom function and you have to check on that function.

Comment: Also are you getting a result when you echo `$row['password']`?

Comment: @Joseph_J yes that echos the hashed pw

Comment: So, neither "It's a match" nor "nope" gets printed?

Comment: Check your db password column.  Make sure the size of the column is set to at least 255 chars.  What is it currently set at?

Comment: Might as well rule this out too, Does the `$_POST['loginPassword']` echo out the user password.

Comment: @Joseph_J currently the column is set to 535, and yes $_POST['loginPassword'] does echo the password.

Comment: @Geshode Nope is printed.

Comment: How many charachters is your hashed password?  Better yet add you hashed password to your post so I can see it.  Add the user supplied password as well. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph_J I have added a pw both hashed and unhashed. I noticed that when I put the hashed pw into a variable and I try to use password_verify it still returns false. I am not sure why. I think the issue might not be the verifying but the hashing. Although I still can't figure out what part of the hashing I am doing wrong.

Comment: The hash you provided and the password you provided to not work for each other.  You are using the wrong password for the hash.

Comment: @Joseph_J Ya I think the db is changing the hash somehow. I know that is the password I input to create the hash.

Answer (score 2):

According to php.net, the second argument of `password_verify()` has to be

> A hash created by password_hash().

Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Your second argument seems to be the result from an SQL query, so if you don't store the password as a hash created by `password_hash()`, `password_verify()` won't be able to work as intended.

Comment: You are correct but I am hashing the pws before I upload them to the database.

Answer (score 1):

So I used the password "myPassword" with `password_hash()` to generate a hash to simulate the hash that is stored on the database.  The hash that I generated is:

```
$signUpPassword = 'myPassword';
$hash = password_hash($signUpPassword,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

The hash that I generated is:

```
'$2y$10$/oQgn.v5Nb3WB1Nf3LK0B.ZAjynRICezFez936e5Kl5vd3KMwO9oa'
```

Your hashes should look similar to the one above.

Then I ran:

```
//Simulated db hash.
$dbHash = '$2y$10$/oQgn.v5Nb3WB1Nf3LK0B.ZAjynRICezFez936e5Kl5vd3KMwO9oa';


$loginPassword = 'myPassword';
$verify = password_verify($loginPassword, $dbHash);

if($verify){

  echo "Its a match";

}else{

  echo "nope";

  }
```

The result was "Its a match".

I really can not see why your code is not working but here is how I would trouble shoot it.

- Make sure your password column is at least 255 chars.  I think I read that the hashes for the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` are always 60 chars but that it may change in the future, so to prevent issues down the road make the column size 255 chars.
- Make sure that the password column type in your db is set to varChar and not a binary data type.
- When generating your hash that you are inserting into the db, make sure the hash that was generated matches the hash that was inserted into your db.  The idea being that maybe your code or the db is adding slashes to you hash.
- Make sure you are using the same password for testing.
- Make sure that your code is not escaping your user inputs or data prior to being fed into the `pasword_hash()` or `password_verify()` functions.
- You are using an email address to query your db to pull the user's record.  Make sure that you do not having more than one of the same email address.  The server may be feeding you the wrong user's hash.
- Make sure your query is returning the correct data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Although I wasn't able to get my original code to work I was able to rewrite it from scratch and everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

this questions is 1 year 6 months old but I ran into same problem. After some effort I found the solution and so wanted to share here.

Problem is in length of value being accepted in MySQL table column for password. I have column type varchar set to store my password and value length for this column was set to 50 characters. I changed the length of password column to 200 characters and it solved my problem. it looks like MySQL accepts input in varchar anyway but accepts only first that many number of characters which are set as column length and that becomes a reason of complete generated hash is not stored in database.

I hope this might help whoever experience this problem again.